# How to access localhost (IDE) from docker network (compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, microservices, development-environment

We are using docker compose for microservice end-to-end development and testing. Basically each compose service has a port mapping from ubiquitous *development port* to container standard production port 8080.

[*UC1*] UI on development mode invokes microservices on *localhost* at known *development ports* (docker port mappings). **It follows one could stop any container on docker network and restart it in the IDE**. UI could still invoke the service, and the service could still invoke other services as long as IDE process binds to *development port* (it's the default profile). This is how we debug microservices through UI with great success.

[*UC2*] However, this solution fails when microservice running in the docker calls back to microservice running in the IDE. That is because containers in the docker compose network are isolated from localhost. They find each other by container name but has no idea of docker host.

How to enable *UC2* with minimal configuration changes and with same flexibility as *UC1*?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you can reach the host using the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).